# Passing ampersand to PowerShell from R

Tags: r, powershell, rstudio

I need to pass a constructed string from R to the Windows Powershell. 
The string looks similar to this:

[http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?file=filename"&"argument=on"&"argument2=on"&"dir=directory](http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?file=filename%22&%22argument=on%22&%22argument2=on%22&%22dir=directory)

Unfortunately, R adds an escape backslash to the string above if I construct it with "paste":

```
fname <- gsub(' ', '', gsub('\n', '',paste('http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?
file=',filename,'"&"
argument=on"&"
argument2=on"&"
dir=',directory,'"&",
sep='')))
```

In R, the variable fname now contains following string:

```
'http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?file=filename\"&\"argument=on\"&\"argument2=on\"&\"dir=directory
```

When passed to the powershell via the command

```
system("powershell Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?file=filename\"&\"argument=on\"&\"argument2=on\"&\"dir=directory' -outfile C:\test.dat")
```

, PowerShell of course complains about because of the backslashes.

```
cat fname
```

prints the string in the R-shell as it should be passed to the PowerShell (namely without the backslashes):

```
http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?file=test"&"argument=on"&"argument2=on"&"dir=somedir
```

I thought of writing the command to a file, executing a "sed"-like system command (e.g.

```
"powershell get-content somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"}")
```

to remove the backslashes in the file, and passing the file as a command to the PowerShell. But I will again have problems passing the backslash in "expression" from R to the powershell. Any ideas?

Reproducible code:

```
filename <- "test"
directory <- "somedir"
fname <- gsub(' ', '', gsub('\n', '',paste('http://www.host.com/cgi-bin/something.pl?
file=',filename,'"&"
argument=on"&"
argument2=on"&"
dir=',directory,
sep='')))
system(paste('powershell Invoke-WebRequest ',fname,' -outfile C:\\Windows\\temp\\test.dat',sep=""))
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `&` character with `\`` (back-tick)?

Comment: @Bill_Steward: Well, the thing is: I do not escape anything. R automatically adds "escape-backslashes" as soon as you try to add a quote to a string.
Example:
    string1 <- 'This is a quote "test'
Leads to
    "This is a quote \"test"
in the R-Shell.

Comment: You are executing a PowerShell cmdlet using the PowerShell command line. To avoid confusion and problems, I would probably recommend creating a temporary file containing the PowerShell command you want to run and run it using `powershell -File`.